# Ruby on Rails, nginx and unicorn "The page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I recently set up my private little server with nginx and unicorn to get into the backend stuff with Ruby on Rails.

To test things out I just made a little scaffold app, which seems to be working fine.

But, from time to time after I refresh the site I get an 404 Error

[image]

This error can be forced to appear if I refresh the site very often in short periods (e.g. hitting F5 10x times as fast as possible)

Is this some standard DDOS protection?
I couldn't find anything in the logs (neither in unicorn nor the nginx logs).

Here are my configs:
**nginx App config**

```
upstream app {
# Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/home/ruby/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name munichmetal.de app.munichmetal.de;

root /home/ruby/app/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**unicorn config**

```
# set path to application
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
working_directory app_dir


# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 5
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

I can also provide the logs if needed.
My first guess was that with the convention over configuration paradigm there might be some sort of built-in DDOS protection in unicorn, but I couldn't find anything.
So any tipps in pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Did you try to set `fail_timeout` param value to default? By default it's equal for 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you referencing to the nginx config? In there the fail_timeout ist set to 0 

`upstream app {
# Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
server unix:/home/ruby/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}`